# How can I encrypt specific mongodb collections

Tags: mongodb, encryption

I would like to encrypt a few MongoDB collections that contain sensitive data. The requirement is to encrypt specific collections where CRUD operations will be performed.

I am aware of Field Encryption; however, is there any option to apply encryption at the collection level?

Comment: What do you mean by *encryption at collection level*? You could be looking for [encryption at rest](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-encryption-at-rest/) which is available in MongoDB enterprise. Nevertheless, stackoverflow is not a place for asking for such a recommendation. Try https://dba.stackexchange.com/